# ImportError ''No Module Named Pandas'', installed by Miniconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

thanks for checking out my question.

I know this question has been posted a couple of times and I went through answers carefully, but none of them could solve my problem. So I have to post it, thanks for understanding.

My Scenario is:
I tried to install Pandas on my Python 2.7 (windows 7). I used Miniconda to install it and tested code to make sure I did install it. But from python command line, it gave me an ImportError 'No Module named Pandas' (detail is in below)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

So I tried again to install it via Pip, and I am right, according to the terminal, Pandas was already installed. Please see below:
[image]

Then I run test code from Python command line, still get 'No module named Pandas' error. Got confused here...

Comment: Show us the actual, exact error message, copy-pasted from actual interpreter output.

Comment: check your path, not sure what the windows equivalent is

Comment: thanks for the advice @user2357112 I edit my question according to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryPolonskiy  Sorry that I am kinda newbie here, could you enlighten me more? I put all the Pandas related files under Python folder, is it right?

Comment: If you installed it in a virtualenv, did you run Python with that virtualenv activated?

Comment: @user2357112   well...i am sure i got that env activated, but how to run Python with that env?

Comment: It should be as simple as running the `python` command from the command prompt where you activated the virtualenv.

Comment: I see, I tried that out, but still get above ImportError...

Answer (score 0):

It works if you open Anaconda terminal (instead of Python terminal) and run test code. The 'importError' is gone.